# Are there any models that explain the cause of the dual symmetry-breaking of the in electrodynamics?

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry-breaking, magnetic-monopoles

Source-free Maxwell eqautions a dual symmetry between electric and magnetic fields is obvious. But in the presence of electric charge, such symmetry is broken. Recover it possible by an introduction in the theory of magnetic charge. However, here are some problem with Lagrangian formulation of the theory. Is there in modern literature theories that explain the reasons for the absence of a magnetic charge by some mechanism of symmetry-breaking?

Comment: It might be worthwhile looking into the geometric algebra formulation of Maxwell's equations. This method reduces the four equations into a single equation ∇ F = J/cє. I'm not too familiar with the theory of magnetic monopoles, but I don't see the need for them, since the formulation is quite elegant without them.